# Continuity of Rational and Irrational

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose f(x) = x - 1 if x is rational and f(x) = 1 - x if x is irrational. Is f continuous at x = 0?

I can convince myself that it's both continuous and discontinuous by thinking about the density of rationals and irrationals, so I'm really confused now. Can someone explain the answer please?

Comment: Do you know the sequential characterization of continuity of a function $f$ ?

Comment: Follow the definitions *completely* and to the letter.  The answer, by the way, is that $x = 0$ is the only point it is continuous.

Comment: You sure, @flea?

Comment: @fleablood Careful that you don't misread the functions.  One of the more common functions you might be thinking of would be something like $g(x)=\begin{cases}x&\text{if}~x\in\Bbb Q\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.  The function here however is different and the only continuous point will be at $x=1$.  (*think of it almost as if $f$ is two lines simultaneously, their intersection point $(1,0)$ is the only time at which they agree.  this can be formalized*)

Comment: That'll teach me to use posting a comment on math.stackexchange as a means of sobering up after a night on the town.  You are of course correct.  But my advise about following the definitions completely and to the letter is still good.  At $x=0$ then "nearby" rational numbers will be "close to" $0 - 1=-1$ and and the irrationals will be close to $1-0 =0$.  so any interval where $x,y$ are close together $f(x),f(y)$ may be nearly $2$ apart.  I'd put that in math language but I think I'm a bit too tipsy.

Comment: Yes,  $1-0 = 0$.  We all know that, right?  :(

Answer (score 2):

$f(0)=-1$, construct a sequence $x_n \to 0$ such that $x_n$ is irrational, what is the limit of $f(x_n)$?

what can you conclude?

Answer (score 1):

$f$ only continuous at $x=1$

If 
$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 x &\text{x is rational}\\
-x &\text{x is irrational}\\
\end{cases}$

Then $f$ is continuous at $x=0$